# How can I change the year range displayed by a FAPI date field?

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a FAPI form with an element of #type => date and it works as expected.

```
$form['date'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => t('Event date:'),
);
```

However, the options displayed in the year field range from 1900 - 2050. I would like to be able to limit this to a much smaller range starting with the current year. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you look at [form_process_date](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_process_date/7) you can see the defaults being added. Probably you'll want to be messing with the $options parameter somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to change every date field—which might have side effects else where on the site—you can easily do it on specific form elements.

```
function example_form(&$form, &$form_state)  {
  $form['birthday'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#title' => t('Birthday'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    // Add a second process function so we can change the years:
    '#process' => array('form_process_date', 'example_fix_year_range'),
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Follow form_process_date() and re-do the years.
 */
function example_fix_year_range($element) {
  $year = format_date(REQUEST_TIME, 'custom', 'Y');
  $element['year']['#options'] = drupal_map_assoc(range($year - 120, $year));
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [hook_element_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/7) to alter the definition of the form element given from [system_element_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_element_info/7).

The default definition is the following one:

```
  $types['date'] = array(
    '#input' => TRUE, 
    '#element_validate' => array('date_validate'), 
    '#process' => array('form_process_date'), 
    '#theme' => 'date', 
    '#theme_wrappers' => array('form_element'),
  );
```

[form_process_date()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_process_date/7) is the function that set the year sub-element. If you replace it with your own process function, or add it, you can alter that limit.
The code used from the default preprocess function is the following one.

```
  // Output multi-selector for date.
  foreach ($order as $type) {
    switch ($type) {
      case 'day':
        $options = drupal_map_assoc(range(1, 31));
        $title = t('Day');
        break;

      case 'month':
        $options = drupal_map_assoc(range(1, 12), 'map_month');
        $title = t('Month');
        break;

      case 'year':
        $options = drupal_map_assoc(range(1900, 2050));
        $title = t('Year');
        break;
    }

    $element[$type] = array(
      '#type' => 'select', 
      '#title' => $title, 
      '#title_display' => 'invisible', 
      '#value' => $element['#value'][$type], 
      '#attributes' => $element['#attributes'], 
      '#options' => $options,
    );
  }
```

As alternative, you can implement [hook_preprocess_date()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7), which is executed when [theme_date()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_date/7) is called. (In Drupal 7, every theme function executes preprocess hooks, not just a theme function using a template file.) Doing so, you can alter the form element the preprocess function gets in `$variables['element']`.

I would rather use the latter method, even though both the methods would work; it is simpler, as it doesn't require two hooks.

Comment: I implemented the latter solution as you suggested and it worked like a charm. Thanks!