# How can I change the selectable years in a date field?

Tags: 8, datetime

I have a date field, `birthday`, created with the Date module. By default, the selectable years are 1900-2050.  This makes no sense for birthdays so I want to change it to only show years from `1900-(current year-18)`.

How can I do this?

There is a [solution for Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31214/how-can-i-change-the-year-range-displayed-by-a-fapi-date-field) but that code does not work in Drupal 8 because [form_process_date()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_process_date/7.x) does not exist in Drupal 8.

This is the full error:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'form_process_date' not found or invalid function name in Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->doBuildForm() (line 993 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php).
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['account']['birthday']['#process'] = array('form_process_date', 'mymodule_fix_year_range');
```

Comment: `drupal_map_assoc` is a really basic function that you could re-make in about a minute, but the link in your question actually contains an example of the replacement method (using the bog standard `array_combine()`). Is there a reason you can't use that?

Comment: Which widget are you using?  Datetime or datelist?

Comment: @mpdonadio Field type: `date`, Widget: `Select list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to add a `#process` to this.

The **Select List** widget is based around the [`Datelist`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21Element%21Datelist.php/class/Datelist/8.4.x) element.

Per the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21Element%21Datelist.php/function/Datelist%3A%3AprocessDatelist/8.4.x) (and I don't know why the are on that method and not `::getInfo()`.  You should be able to form alter this, and change the '#date_year_range' key.  This is a string value, which defaults to '1900:2050' (min-year:max-year).  You would just need to have some logic to build it up in the proper format.

Answer (score 5):

@mpdonadio♦'s answer provides the explanation.  Here is the actual code I used:

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_birthday']['widget'][0]['value']['#date_year_range'] = '1950:2005';
```